# How can I extract the original URL from a redirected URL?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a URL like this one

```
let RURL = 'https://out.psychologytoday.com/us/profile/398490/website-redirect?_ga=2.242270594.1285330155.1596203882-512347135.1596038085'
```

and its redirect to this URL `https://www.sinclairmethod.org/`

Now how can I get the original URL to which it is getting redirected?

Comment: You if you trigger the navigation using `history.pushState`, you can store arbitrary information in the `state` object (such as the url of the previous state.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API   -----   Alternatively, you could probably always store it in the browser's `localStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript from the redirected page, you can get the referer URL from:

```
document.referrer
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: for that I have to go on that page first, but here I wanted to extract the original one from the redirected one without go to that redirected page

Its work on browser 
`const htmlContent = fetch('https://out.psychologytoday.com/us/profile/398490/website-redirect?_ga=2.242270594.1285330155.1596203882-512347135.1596038085').then(res => console.log(res.url) )`
I want the same thing to work in nodejs